# how to persist spring session in h2 database

Tags: spring, h2, spring-session

```
@EnableJdbcHttpSession 
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedDatabase dataSource() {
            return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder() 
                    .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                    .addScript("org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-h2.sql").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
            return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource); 
    }
}
```

I find this config in spring doc, but I want to save session in file rather then in memory, How could I modify my config

Comment: Do you read Spring-Session document ? http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-jdbc-xml.html#running-the-httpsession-jdbc-xml-sample-application

Comment: yes, I use java config provided by Spring-Session document, but this config can only save session in memory, I want save in file so I can get session when server has been restarted